# How to put a unicode character in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to do this:

```
  ArticleTitle = ArticleTitle.Replace(" - ", "&#8212;");
```

To get a — to appear in front of the text. It doesn't work. And it appeared &#8212; What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 4):

Use the actual Unicode character, embedded in a string literal (according to the normal C# source code rules) - and let the XML API handle whatever escaping or encoding it needs to do:

```
ArticleTitle = ArticleTitle.Replace(" - ", "\u8212");
```